# MahApps.Metro MetroTabControl with Caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn, mahapps.metro

i try to raise the TabItemClosingEvent of the Controls:MetroTabControl.

XAML:

```
<Controls:MetroTabControl cal:Message.Attach="[Event TabItemClosingEvent] = [Action CloseConnection($source, $eventArgs)];" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding Connections.View}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConnection}"  Margin="10,0">
```

Code:

```
public void CloseConnection(object sender, BaseMetroTabControl.TabItemClosingEventArgs e)
{
e.Cancel = false;
}
```

CloseConnection is never called. Somebody can see my fault?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to make MahApps work with Caliburn's short syntax either.

However, the long syntax works for me:

```
<Controls:MetroTabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
                            Background="{x:Null}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Connections.View}" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConnection}"  Margin="10,0" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TabItemClosingEvent">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="CloseConnection">
                <cal:Parameter Value="$source" />
                <cal:Parameter Value="$eventArgs" />
            </cal:ActionMessage>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Controls:MetroTabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works very well with the LONG syntax.